# Sinon.js spy does not work correctly in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have a mocha test case, where I want to spy on an existing functions. Unfortunately sinon.js does not count the calls:

```
    it("should work with spy", function() {
    var func = function() {
    };

    var spy = sinon.spy(func);

    func();
    func();

    console.log(spy.callCount);

    // fails
    assert(spy.CallCount == 2);
    /* works:
    var secondSpy = sinon.spy();

    secondSpy();

    console.log(secondSpy.callCount);
    */
});
```

What could be probably be wrong?

Comment: I just want to check, but if you change your console log to `func.callCount`, what do you get?

Comment: "undefined" (I tried that too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to call the spy like you do in the working example. The only instance (see [line 21](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/blob/master/lib/sinon/spy.js#L21)) where the function can be called is when it's inside of an object (e.g. `sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax")`) as it will overwrite it with the spy properties. In the other two cases where you can create a spy it will only return a spy that mimics the original function.

But this should be quite simple for testing modules as you can use the method I previously mentioned - `sinon.spy(moduleName, "methodToSpy");`. Then when you call that method directly, you will also be able to get the spy properties. To then remove the spy properties you would need to call `moduleName.methodToSpy.restore()`.

Comment: Interestingly, after reading this answer twice, i *still* don't understand why OPs example does not work.

Comment: AH! After reading again: Call the spy, not the original function